# Locale getDisplayLanguage() method return LanguageCode in android Lollipop

Tags: locale, android-5.0-lollipop, multilingual

I am making an application(multilingual) and when i test it over android lollipop then i saw that `Locale.getDisplayLanguage()` method returns `en_us` for English(United States) and Nederlands is `nl_nl` instead of returning English or Dutch respectively.

Comment: I am having the same problem. It works fine using pre-Lollipop (virtual) devices but on Lollipop devices I observed the same behaviour as you did.